# Testing create resource with curl return status code 500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, curl

I am manually testing the Api for Rails 3 create action with curl but i keep getting `Internal server error(500)`. I have a product model and here is the create action in my controller and the commands I have tried....

```
#command
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json"  -X POST -d "product[product_name]=dvd"  http://localhost:3000/api/products  

#controller
module Api  
  class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

     def create
       @product = Product.new(params[:product])
       respond_to do |format|
         if @product.save
           format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
           format.json { render json: @product, status: :created, location: @product }
         else
           format.html { render action: "new" }
           format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
         end
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

What am i missing here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can see error message in server log. `

Comment: in The log says `WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: product_name):
  app/controllers/api/products_controller.rb:72:in `new'
  app/controllers/api/products_controller.rb:72:in `create'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the MassAssignmentSecurity error, it looks like you just need to make the product_name field accessible on your model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :product_name
  #... other code...
end
```

Comment: ` (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("category_id", "created_at", "details", "product_name", "publisher_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["category_id", nil], ["created_at", Wed, 21 Nov 2012 16:21:30 UTC +00:00], ["details", nil], ["product_name", "dvd"], ["publisher_id", nil], ["updated_at", Wed, 21 Nov 2012 16:21:30 UTC +00:00]]
   (5.9ms)  commit transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `api_v1_products_controller_product_url' for #<Api::V1::ProductsController:0x007f94a3a81788>):`

Comment: I am getting the error above , seems like it is trying to insert then fails.

Comment: Looks like the insert works, but then it's trying to build a URL based on the current controller. You might be better using respond_with. Checkout this [API tutorial](http://davidwparker.com/2010/03/09/api-in-rails-respond-to-and-respond-with/)

Comment: Here's another link that might be useful http://asciicasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3

Comment: Thank you so much , everything IS fine now.